# Can't add new account VS 2017 Experimental Instance

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Anybody encountered this kind of scenario?

After I typed my password, it will load and repeat again the login process. I cannot add my account in Visual Studio 2017 Community.

[image]

Comment: can you login to your MS account on MS site: https://account.microsoft.com/?

Comment: yes, I can login to my Microsoft account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this by clicking "***Start Visual Studio to fix this issue***" link and not the sign in or add account.

Hope this helps you out.